How to Implement Resizable, Movable, and Removable Dragable Rectangle in React Native for Both iOS and Web?
I am looking to implement a feature in React Native (which supports both iOS and web) that allows users to draw a resizable rectangle by dragging. After drawing, users should be able to resize, move, or delete the rectangle, and the coordinates of the rectangle should be recorded.
I found that the react-konva library provides this functionality perfectly (for example: https://konvajs.org/docs/react/Transformer.html), but it is only available for web React and is not suitable for React Native. Is there something similar available for React Native?
So far, I have tried using react-native-gesture-handler, but the results are not even close to what react-konva offers
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, Platform } from 'react-native';
import Svg, { Circle, Polygon } from 'react-native-svg';
import { GestureEvent, PanGestureHandler, PanGestureHandlerEventPayload } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const DrawRectangle = () => {
  const [start, setStart] = useState(null);
  const [end, setEnd] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ w: 0, h: 0 });

  const onPress = (event) => {
    const { x, y, translationX, translationY } = event.nativeEvent;
    if (!start) setStart({ x: y, y: x });
    setDimensions({ w: translationX, h: translationY });
  };

  const onEnd = () => {
    if (!start) return;

    setEnd(start);
    setStart(null);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={onPress} onEnded={onEnd}>
        <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
          <View
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              backgroundColor: 'blue',
              top: start?.x ?? end?.x,
              left: start?.y ?? end?.y,
              width: dimensions?.w ?? 0,
              height: dimensions?.h ?? 0
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </View>
  );
};

export default DrawRectangle;

Here's a brief outline of my requirements:
Draw a rectangle by dragging.
Resize the rectangle after it is drawn.
Move the rectangle to a different location.
Delete the rectangle if needed.
Record the coordinates of the rectangle.
Could anyone suggest a suitable library or approach to achieve this in React Native for both iOS and web?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

If you use react-native-reanimated and react-native-gesture-handler you can get your desired result (demo). If you know the top left coordinate and the bottom right coordinates, you can get the width and the height:
export default function useRectValues(initPoint1, initPoint2) {
  const point1 = useSharedValue(initPoint1 || [0, 0]);
  const point2 = useSharedValue(initPoint2 || [0, 0]);
  const width = useDerivedValue(() =>
    Math.abs(point1.value[0] - point2.value[0])
  );
  const height = useDerivedValue(() =>
    Math.abs(point1.value[1] - point2.value[1])
  );
  return {
    point1,
    point2,
    width,
    height,
  };
}

Rather than holding all of these values in the parent component you can create a component and expose a custom ref that allows you to manipulate the SharedValues:
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from 'react';
import {isWithinBounds} from './helpers'
import Animated, {
  useSharedValue,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useDerivedValue,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import useRectValues from './useRectValues';

export default forwardRef(function MoveableRect(
  { isActive, title, initialPoint1,initialPoint2 },
  ref
) {
  // hook that creates two animated values and
  // then derive width and height from those values
  const { point1, point2, width, height } = useRectValues(
    initialPoint1,
    initialPoint2
  );
  // expose functions that will be called by gesture handler events
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      move(x, y) {
        point1.value = [point1.value[0] + x, point1.value[1] + y];
        point2.value = [point2.value[0] + x, point2.value[1] + y];
      },
      resize(x, y) {
        point2.value = [x, y];
      },
      // e should have x and y
      isWithinBounds(e){
        return isWithinBounds(e,point1,point2)
      }
    };
  });
  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: point1.value[0],
      top: point1.value[1],
      width: width.value,
      height: height.value,
      backgroundColor: isActive ? 'green' : 'purple',
      zIndex: 10,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    };
  });
  return (
    <Animated.View style={animatedStyle}>
      <Text>{title}</Text>
    </Animated.View>
  );
});

When the user draws, update your SharedValues; at the end of a draw store SharedValues into state. With the state, you can render the rectangle and use the ref to get the rectangles current location and/or update the rectangle's location:
import { Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import Animated, { useAnimatedStyle, runOnJS } from 'react-native-reanimated';
import {
  GestureHandlerRootView,
  GestureDetector,
  Gesture,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import useRectValues, { makeRectValues } from './useRectValues';
import MoveableRect from './MoveableRect';

const MODES = {
  draw: 'draw',
  drag: 'drag',
  resize: 'resize',
};

export default function App() {
  // keep track of rectangle to manipulate
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(-1);
  const [rectangles, setRectangles] = useState([]);
  const { point1, point2, width, height } = useRectValues();
  const [mode, setMode] = useState(MODES.draw);
  const rectangleRefs = useRef([]);
  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: point1.value[0],
      top: point1.value[1],
      width: width.value,
      height: height.value,
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      zIndex: 10,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    };
  });
  const pan = Gesture.Pan()
    // if you remove this you need to manually call
    // runOnJS everytime you call a setter in all gesture callbacks
    .runOnJS(true)
    .onStart((e) => {
      if (mode === MODES.draw) {
        point1.value = [e.x, e.y];
      } else {
        const index = rectangleRefs.current.findIndex((ref) => {
          return ref?.isWithinBounds?.(e, point1, point2);
        });
        setActiveIndex(index);
      }
    })
    .onChange((e) => {
      if (mode === MODES.draw) {
        point2.value = [e.x, e.y];
      } else if (activeIndex >= 0) {
        if (mode === MODES.resize) {
          rectangleRefs.current[activeIndex]?.resize(e.x, e.y);
        }
        if (mode === MODES.drag) {
          rectangleRefs.current[activeIndex]?.move(
            e.changeX * 0.7,
            e.changeY * 0.7
          );
        }
      }
    })
    // store value into state and reset
    .onEnd(() => {
      if (mode === MODES.draw) {
        const corners = {
          point1: point1.value,
          point2: point2.value,
        };
        setRectangles((prev) => [...prev, corners]);
        point1.value = [0, 0];
        point2.value = [0, 0];
      }
    });
  // on single tap set mode to draw
  const singleTap = Gesture.Tap()
    .runOnJS(true)
    .onStart((e) => {
      const index = rectangleRefs.current.findIndex((ref) => {
        return ref?.isWithinBounds?.(e, point1, point2);
      });
      // if an object isnt tapped reset to draw
      setMode(index < 0 ? MODES.draw : MODES.drag);
      setActiveIndex(index);
    });
  // on double set to resize
  const doubleTap = Gesture.Tap()
    .runOnJS(true)
    .numberOfTaps(2)
    .onStart((e) => {
      const index = rectangleRefs.current.findIndex((ref) => {
        return ref?.isWithinBounds?.(e, point1, point2);
      });
      if (index >= 0) {
        setActiveIndex(index);
        setMode(MODES.resize);
      }
    });
  // on triple delete
  const tripleTap = Gesture.Tap()
    .runOnJS(true)
    .numberOfTaps(3)
    .onStart((e) => {
      const index = rectangleRefs.current.findIndex((ref) => {
        return ref?.isWithinBounds?.(e, point1, point2);
      });
      if (index >= 0) {
        setRectangles((prev) => prev.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
      }
    });
  const gesture = Gesture.Exclusive(tripleTap, doubleTap, singleTap, pan);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <GestureHandlerRootView>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
          Single tap object to enter drag mode.{'\n'}
          Double tap to enter resize mode.{'\n'}
          Triple tap object to delete.
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Button title="Enter Draw Mode" onPress={() => setMode(MODES.draw)} />
          <Button
            title="Clear"
            onPress={() => {
              setRectangles([]);
              setMode(MODES.draw);
              setActiveIndex(-1);
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
          <View style={styles.drawContainer}>
            <Animated.View style={animatedStyle}>
              <Text>{rectangles.length + 1}</Text>
            </Animated.View>
            {rectangles.map((props, i) => (
              <MoveableRect
                initialPoint1={props.point1}
                initialPoint2={props.point2}
                isActive={i == activeIndex}
                ref={(ref) => (rectangleRefs.current[i] = ref)}
                title={i + 1}
              />
            ))}
            <Text style={styles.floatingText}>Mode: {mode.toUpperCase()} </Text>
          </View>
        </GestureDetector>
      </GestureHandlerRootView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 8,
  },
  drawContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
    margin: 5,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  floatingText: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 20,
    width: '100%',
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
});

